Is there a way to avoid new paragraph?
Is it possible to avoid a paragraph/line break in the compiled document between different paragraphs of code? Something like \noindent but specifically for the paragraph break:
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

% commented text, figure or table

%\noparagraph ???
consectetur adipiscing elit

It can be helpful when editing/commenting certain blocks of text that one may need to replace later or keep for reference, without having to move text around the document.
A "dirty" workaround is to place '%' on empty lines between both paragraphs, but those may also become cumbersome to remove later.

Sorry, but IMHO the question is very unclear. Why are you adding an empty line, if you don't want a paragraph. Just use an empty comment instead. This isn't a dirty workaround it is a correct solution. Deactivating paragraphs IMHO would be a dirty workaround. BTW: There are also packages to deactivate large portions of a document: → https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp

Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311991/latex-avoid-new-paragraph?

basically there is nothing that can be done at the point you indicate, the previous paragraph has already ended and you can't undo that. You could use a command before the blank lines that locally gobbled the \par but using a % is much simpler and less error prone.

The dirty workaround  was use long time ago  the so common ascii sign  % for the comments, forcing to escape every time that it is used for text, instead of one of the thousands signs  good-for-nothing  of utf-8.  Let's hope that such a painful sacrifice has not been in vain. Use it, damn it, but if a command look better for you, see here

Basically there is nothing that can be done at the point you indicate, the previous paragraph has already ended and you can't undo that. You could use a command before the blank lines that locally gobbled the \par but using a % is much simpler and less error prone.
Rather than commenting out the blank line a better solution is really not to add it.  White space in TeX documents (as opposed to specific code conventions such as expl3) should never be seen as code formatting: it is explicit typesetting instructions. An end of line is an instruction to insert an inter-word space, a blank line is \par an instruction to end the current paragraph. (Note that it ends the paragraph not starts a new one, which is one reason why your suggested location of a command to nullify it is too late: you don't want to avoid starting a new paragraph, you want to avoid ending the previous one.)

There is also the comment package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\begin{comment}

 commented text, figure or table

\end{comment}
consectetur adipiscing elit

\end{document}

